# How to refresh an email in Python with win32com Outlook?

Tags: python, outlook-restapi

I have a program that displays my most recent e-mail from Outlook.  If I receive a new e-mail while the program is running, it does not refresh and show the new e-mail.  Any suggestions on how I can do this?

My code is not updating to the newest e-mail:

```
import win32com.client
import os 
import threading # use the Timer 

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.Body

def timer():


    print (body_content) 

    threading.Timer(30, timer).start()

timer()
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the the COM library is not initialized in the new thread.  So I had to add this to the function

```
    import pythoncom           # These 2 lines are here because COM library
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()   # is not initialized in the new thread
```

This would be the correct code that works:

```
def timer():

    import pythoncom           # These 2 lines are here because COM library
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()   # is not initialized in the new thread

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                        # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                        # any other folder

    messages = inbox.Items
    message = messages.GetLast()
    body_content = message.Body

    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print (body_content) # orginally used body_content.encode("utf-8") to fixed character encoding issue
                         # caused by Windows CMD.  But then figured out you can type 'chcp 65001' in cmd
    threading.Timer(30, timer).start() # refresh rate goes her
```